# Can't publish using Visual studio 2017 (community version)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, exe

I have a small project with python finished and ready to publish (transforming everything into one executable); but, when I disposed to do so, I realized that the "publish" button was disabled. I tried looking explanations in the internet, but didn't get anything. Then, I searched for a publish alternative, but the ones I found seemed to be overcomplicated and untrusty.

Because of that, now I come here to ask for your knowledge/help on this matter that troubles me.

I stay tuned to your answers and wish you a great day :)

Update: tried with PyInstaller and cx_freeze. PyInstaller gives me the:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

And cx_freeze creates everything, but, when I run the executable, it closes inmediatly (and yes, I tried adding an input("promt...") at the end, without success).

By chance, you will not know how to solve any of these problems? :/

Comment: Is that option ever available for Python projects?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to your project when you publish?

Comment: For what I see on the internet, it is.

I want that it converts all my project into one executable.

Comment: See the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: The only thing that I got from that was that: "Because Python is an interpreted language, Python projects in Visual Studio don't produce a stand-alone executable like other compiled language projects (C#, for example). For more information, see questions and answers." I'll just try the overcomplicated stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. I used pyintaller (cx_freeze didn't work), but in the .spec added this at the start:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

And in the Analysis added:

```
hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors',
        'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs',
        'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree',
        'sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation',
        'sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools',
        'sklearn.utils.lgamma',
        'sklearn.utils.weight_vector',
        'sklearn.utils.fixes',
        'sklearn.tree._utils',
        'sklearn.utils.extmath',
        'sklearn.metrics.ranking']
```

Hope it helps someone so they don't lose all day searching for the solution like I did :P